# C# Returning Data from a Task

Tags: c#, .net, task

Hi I have the following short code extract. The aim of the code is to return a person object from a Task and obtain the result so that it's accessible in main.

The code I have is as follows but I'm getting two errors when compiling.

> Error 2   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   multi_threaded_tasks.Program.ExecuteAsync_GetPerson()' has the wrong
>   return type
>  Error 1   An object reference is required for the
>   non-static field, method, or property
>   'multi_threaded_tasks.Program.ExecuteAsync_GetPerson()'

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and any assistance you can provide would be helpful. P.S If there is a better way to return objects I'm open to suggestions but I'd like the functions calls to be separate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace multi_threaded_tasks
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string first_name;
        public string last_name;
        //Constructor
        public Person()
        {
            first_name="";
            last_name="";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main started:");
            CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
            Task<Person> t_person = Task<Person>.Factory.StartNew(
                function: ExecuteAsync_GetPerson, 
                cancellationToken: cancelSource.Token, 
                creationOptions: TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, 
                scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);

            Person main_person = t_person.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("The person first name:" + main_person.first_name);
            Console.WriteLine("The person last name:" + main_person.last_name);
            Console.WriteLine("Main Ended:");
        }

        async Task<Person> ExecuteAsync_GetPerson()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteAsync_GetPeople started:");
            Person a_person = new Person();
            a_person.first_name="";
            a_person.last_name="";
            await Task.Delay(2000); // Wait 2 seconds
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteAsync_GetPeople returning:");
            return a_person;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You're not initializing your `CancellationSource` and that's why you're getting `NullReferenceException`. 2. `StartNew` expects `Func<TResult>`, not `Func<Task<TResult>>` and that's causing the other error.

Comment: Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, if you're on the .NET 4.5+, unless you're actually know, what are you doing.  Use `Task.Run` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense anyway.

Since this is a console application with two methods, and one of them is application entry point, you can't get any benefits from asynchronous methods, because you want to get task result in your main method. This means, that main thread will be blocked and will not be able to cancel anything.

I've thrown away some garbage from your code and added another sample `async` method. This is, possibly, what you want:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task<Person> GetPersonAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetPersonAsync started.");

        var person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Doe"
        };

        await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken); // Wait 5 seconds
        Console.WriteLine("GetPersonAsync ended.");
        return person;
    }

    static async Task TestGetPersonAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestGetPersonAsync started.");

        try
        {
            var person = await GetPersonAsync(cancellationToken);

            Console.WriteLine("The person first name:" + person.FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("The person last name:" + person.LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("TestGetPersonAsync ended.");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestGetPersonAsync cancelled.");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main started:");

        // let's get person asynchronously;
        // this object will contain our cancellation token;            
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        // dummy variable here is needed to aviod compiler warning,
        // since TestGetPersonAsync is async, and we will not (and cannot) await it
        var _ = TestGetPersonAsync(cts.Token);

        // if TestGetPersonAsync is not finished yet, we are going to cancel it;
        // wait for a new line
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to cancel TestGetPersonAsync and to exit application.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (!_.IsCompleted)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Main ended.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was supposed to be a sampler code to understand the concept of returning an object in c# using tasks, without making the code to complex to read or understand. I understand that main is doing nothing in reality other workloads would be running, but for simplicity these were omitted. Thanks for the nice solution though!

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` has the following definition:

```
public Task<TResult> StartNew(Func<TResult> function...
```

while you are trying to pass

```
public Task<TResult> StartNew(Func<Task<TResult>> function...
```

If you want to start an async method, you can use:

```
Task<Person> t_person = Task.Run(() => a());
Person main_person = t_person.Result;
```